# Having trouble getting a Request Token for Yahoo Oauth

Tags: oauth

When I make the GET request, Yahoo responds with oauth_problem = consumer_key_unknown.

I am following this documentation: http://developer.yahoo.com/oauth/guide/oauth-requesttoken.html

I am using the consumer key and secret given to me by Yahoo.  I am not specifying a callback URL.  Instead, I set it to 'oob,' as suggested by the documentation.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.  Got it now.  The Yahoo developer page has some screwy UI and the "--" at the end of my consumer key was not showing up.

Also, you don't need the quotes for oob and the signature method.  Now it works fine.